# Why isn't it the same with canvas, and webgl renderer? (three.js)

Tags: javascript, opera, html5-canvas, webgl, three.js

I try to render a sphere with three.js, but if I render it with canvasRenderer, then there are grey lines on the sphere

code: http://jsfiddle.net/jzpSJ/

screenshot: http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg209/scaled.php?server=209&filename=canvase.png&res=landing

But if I render it with webGL renderer in opera next, then it looks awful

code: http://jsfiddle.net/jzpSJ/1/

screenshot: http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg51/scaled.php?server=51&filename=webglopera.png&res=landing

In google chrome it looks as it should be.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CanvasRenderer:**

Change material definition, `overdraw: false` must be `overdraw: true`

**WebGLRenderer:**

WebGL and Opera? Are you testing the alpha version? A lot of things still broken.

Comment: I think, it's a three.js bug with the webgl renderer, because this demo works perfectly in opera: http://learningwebgl.com/lessons/lesson11/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `dirty` and/or `dynamic` flags. See [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1155) and [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates).

This doesn't really answer your *question*, but it could be a fix.